# cuda nvcc cross compiler

Tags: windows, cuda, cross-compiling, nvcc

I want to compile CUDA code on mac but make it executable on Windows.

Is there a way to set up an nvcc CUDA cross compiler?

The problem is that my desktop windows will be inaccessible for a while due to traveling, however i do not want to wasted time by waiting til i get back and compile the code. If I have to wait then it would be a waste of time to debug the code and make sure it compiles correct and the likes. My mac is not equipped with cuda capable hardware though.

Comment: I use CMake build system for cross compiling. Did you looked at it?

Comment: not yet. is it the same as building a regular cross compiler?

Comment: Nvcc isn't a compiler. It relies on the host compiler to do most of the compilation (including much of the GPU code compilation). To compile for windows, that requires the visual studio compiler, and the requirement is non-negotiable. You can install the tool chain on OS X without an NVIDIA GPU. You just won't be able to run the result OS X executables.

Comment: Yes, but I think I's easiest way to work with cross-compilation toolchains. You say CMake there is your toolchain file and it set all flags, compilers paths and so on. And you nvcc can recognize that compiler it mast use actually

Comment: cross compiling means compiling for a target architecture which is different from the architecture of the host doing the compilation. You can't cross compile for Windows targets on OS X or Linux because the Microsoft compiler can't run on OS X or Linux. CMake can't change that.

Comment: if you have a cross compiler on mac, can you use that to compile cuda for windows like you would for compiling other programs with windows?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer, is no, it is not possible.

It is a common misconception, but `nvcc` isn't actually a compiler. It is a *compiler driver*, and it relies heavily on the host C++ compiler in order to steer compilation both host and device code. To compile CUDA for Windows, you *must* using the Microsoft C++ compiler. That compiler can't be run on Linux or OS X, so cross compilation to a Windows target is not possible unless you are doing the compilation on a Windows host (so 32/64 bit cross compilation is possible, for example).

The other two CUDA platforms are equally incompatible, despite requiring gcc for compilation, because the back ends are different (Linux is an elf platform, OS X is a mach platform), so even cross compilation between OS X and Linux isn't possible.

You have two choices if compilation on the OS X platform is the goal

1. Install the OS X toolkit. Even though your hardware doesn't have a compatible GPU, you can still install the toolkit and compile code.
2. Install the Windows toolkit and visual studio inside a virtual windows installation (or a physical boot camp installation), and compile code inside Windows on the Mac. Again, you don't need NVIDIA compatible hardware to do this.

If you want to run code without a CUDA GPU, there is a non-commercial ([GPU Ocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/)) and commercial ([PGI CUDA-x86](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cuda-x86.htm)) option you could investigate.

Comment: i was thinking of using bootcamp to get windows then compile it, but i though it needed to have the hardware for compilation also. but if i compile it without the hardware, would it still be posible to run it on another machine with the hardware, or do i have to compile again? thanks

Comment: If you use the same host and device architectures, CUDA toolkit and Microsoft runtime versions on both machines, I don't see why it wouldn't work, although I have no experience in doing so.

Comment: There are also some cross-compilers that compile CUDA to OpenCL, such as the [Coriander project](https://github.com/hughperkins/coriander).

Comment: @AndersonGreen OpenCL is now deprecated on OSX, so that doesn't help much